# Swift - Automatically save pdf file to Files app On My iPhone

Tags: swift, pdf, download, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am in desperate need of help.

I am trying to create an app which allows the user to save the pdf file from a link such as the example one I gave in the subjectLinks array, all those links point to a pdf page and I am trying to download it and save it in my app. So far, I have scoured everywhere and found a way to do it using the Files app, so what I'm doing in the code is downloading the data of the pdf and opening it using UIDocument and presentPreview to display it and I have managed to allow the user to share the downloaded file and save it to Files as well.

However the problem arises as I want to make it so that when the user clicks download the file is automatically saved to the Files app in a directory so that the user does not need to click the option button then choose Save to Files and then look for where to save it. Is that possible??

If that is not possible, at least when the user chooses the option button and clicks Save to Files, it would automatically create a separate directory where the user can see and pdf file can be saved?

I want to do this as most times, when Save to Files is chosen, saving 'On My iPhone' is not available as there is no directory or such present so it can only be saved to google drive or iCloud Drive and this is a major inconvenience.

Sorry for the long post. BUT I WOULD BE EXTREMELY GRATEFUL IF ANYONE COULD HELP SOLVE MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH IN ADVANCE :)

P.S everything in my code works perfectly fine so far, its just I am absolutely clueless as to how to implement the features I have outlines above?

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

let subjectLinks = ["https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/Cambridge%20International%20Examinations%20(CIE)/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Accounting%20(9706)/2015%20Jun/9706_s15_qp_42.pdf", "https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/Cambridge%20International%20Examinations%20(CIE)/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Economics%20(9708)/2017%20Jun/9708_s17_qp_12.pdf", "https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/Cambridge%20International%20Examinations%20(CIE)/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/2018-May-June/9709_s18_qp_12.pdf"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self as? UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return subjectLinks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = subjectLinks[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    // 1
    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Download" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void in
        // 2
        let downloadMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Download this paper", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

        downloadMenu.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in self.storeAndShare(withURLString: self.subjectLinks[indexPath.row])}))
        downloadMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(downloadMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    // 3
    let rateAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Rate" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:IndexPath) -> Void in
        // 4
        let rateMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Rate this App", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let appRateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Rate", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {action in SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()})
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

        rateMenu.addAction(appRateAction)
        rateMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(rateMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    // 5
    return [shareAction,rateAction]
}

}
    extension TableViewController {
    /// This function will set all the required properties, and then provide a preview for the document
    func share(url: URL) {
        documentInteractionController.url = url
        documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
        documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
        documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }

    /// This function will store your document to some temporary URL and then provide sharing, copying, printing, saving options to the user
    func storeAndShare(withURLString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: withURLString) else { return }
        /// START YOUR ACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            do {
                let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
                let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.pdf")
                try data.write(to: fileURL)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.share(url: fileURL)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
extension TableViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    /// If presenting atop a navigation stack, provide the navigation controller in order to animate in a manner consistent with the rest of the platform
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        guard let navVC = self.navigationController else {
            return self
        }
        return navVC
    }
}
```

Comment: Saving a file without user's consent?  You scare me.

Comment: hahaha @ElTomato no don't worry, it only saves it when the user clicks download and chooses to save it, it just does it automatically to a location without the user having to choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of download any pdf file and automatically save inside files folder of iPhone.

```
    let urlString = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let fileName = String((url!.lastPathComponent)) as NSString
    //Mark:  Create destination URL
    let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
    //Mark: Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: urlString)
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            //Mark: Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                do {
                    //Mark: Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file
                    let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                    for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                        if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (let err) {
                    print("error: \(err)")
                }
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: This solution still opens UIActivityViewController and asks user to select save option, can we save directly to Files folder without opening UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Need to add permission in info.plist

```
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

Step #2: Download document from server url[any document]

```
func downloadPdf(sender:UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Do UI Code here.
        let pdfUrl = self.myOrderListModel?.myorderList?[sender.tag].invoiceUrl ?? ""
        guard let fileURL = URL(string: pdfUrl) else { return }
        var originalUrlStr : String = ""
        print(fileURL.pathExtension)
        if fileURL.pathExtension == ""{
            originalUrlStr = pdfUrl + ".pdf"
        } else {
            originalUrlStr = pdfUrl
        }
        guard let originalUrl = URL(string: originalUrlStr) else { return }
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: originalUrl)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

extension InvoiceViewController:  URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("File Downloaded Location- ",  location)
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else {
        return
    }
    let docsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destinationPath = docsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationPath)
    do{
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationPath)
        print("File Downloaded Location- ",  destinationPath)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let urlString: String = destinationPath.absoluteString
            self.saveInvoiceToDevice(filePath: urlString)
        }
    }catch let error {
        print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

Step #3: Save downloaded file in Device "Files" Folder

```
    func saveInvoiceToDevice(filePath : String) {
    let fileURL = URL(string: filePath)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL!.path){
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL!.path)
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
        //If user on iPad
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            if activityViewController.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIViewController.popoverPresentationController)) {
            }
        }
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        debugPrint("document was not found")
    }
}
```